# How to populate a single-dimension array with result of a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, arrays, cursor

I have to populate the result of a query into an array in my pl/sql proc.

For example, I have a employeeId `empArr (TYPE empArr IS TABLE OF NUMBER  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;)` and i want to populate this array with the result of a sql statement :

```
    select empId where dept = 'accounts'.
```

Is there a way to do this ? Or would you suggest using cursors to do the job ?

Thx
Cshah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE empArr IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  myEmpArr  empArr;

BEGIN

  SELECT empID
    BULK COLLECT INTO myEmpArr
    FROM empTable
    WHERE dept='accounts';

  -- Do your stuff

END;
/
```

Comment: I don't see where you're setting which table to perform the select statement on in the above example.

Comment: @EddiePrislac you're quite right, I left it out (maybe because I copied the query form the question which also had no table name).  Fixed now.